# How to set webclient proxy to null?

Tags: c#, webclient, windows-phone-8

I tried this code

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Proxy = null;
```

but I get System.Net.Webclient does not contain definition for proxy

Comment: When you say you "get" this message, is this a compilation error?

Comment: No the proxy word is  underlined with the red wavy line and the message appears on mouse hover

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is `System.Net.WebClient` does not contain a definition for proxy.
If you check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient_properties%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) you see that the webclient does not have a property named Proxy.

If you check the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page for the normal webclient (non-Silverlight/non-phone) version you see the Proxy property. But that is not included in the stripped down version for the windows phone, because in your Phone you cant set a proxy.

So no need to set it to null. Since the property doesn't exist. Just remove that line.

Answer (score 0):

WebClient class does not actually contain definition of Proxy for Silverlight.
You can check the reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Dear SynerCoder, Maybe because my internet was slow I think it might be possible that I didn't see your response. You know this Proxy property does not exist for Silverlight. Just showed the same but it wasn't the copy paste obviously. Apologies for misinterpretation! :)